# As short as possible

Tags: visual

**What shape should replace the question mark?**

---

[image]

Comment: For the solution, are you looking for an image file specifically, or if we can give a verbal description of what replaces the ?, would that be sufficient?

Comment: @Vaekor Yeah, preferably an image file and then explaining with words

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution would look like:

> [image]

First,

> We can write the numbers from 1-36 in the squares of the grid in order. Then we can overlay the red lines from the bottom onto that grid.
>  [image]
>  [image]
>  [image]

Then,

> We can look at the numbers in the cells traversed by the line. For the second figure, a cube, its line traces the numbers 1, 8, 27. For the third figure, a hypercube, its line traces the numbers 1, 16. These are the sets of cubic and fourth power numbers less than or equal to 36. The relationship is that if a figure depicts an n-dimensional figure, then the line will trace all integer powers of n less than or equal to 36 in ascending order in the given 6x6 grid.

Therefore,

> The line for the square, a 2 dimensional figure, must trace over all square numbers up to 36 in ascending order. These are 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, and 36, and the result is the following:
>  [image]
>  [image]

Comment: This is indeed the intended solution. Good job!

Answer (score 3):

My best visual representation would look like this:

> [image]

My verbal description (bear with me) would be something like:

> In middle pair, the cube is paired with the shortest distance around the surface area of the cube.  We'll reword this as "the shortest path through the 2-D faces around the 3-D cube".  With that perspective, the third pair is a hypercube (4-D cube) paired with "the shortest path through the 3-D cubes around the 4-D cube", since each "face" of the hypercube is in fact a 3-D cube.  Because of our limited perception of the hypercube, this visually appears as a straight line passing through the cubes.  For the first pair, we therefore need "the shortest path through the 1-D edges around the square", which could take us either up and left, or right and up.

Comment: But where does "Ordered" fit in?

Comment: I took the title to suggest rot13(jr ner svaqvat gur fubegrfg cngu trbzrgevpnyyl), while I took "ordered" to suggest rot13(jr ner neenatrq va beqre ol qvzrafvbanyvgl (vr, gung gur qvzrafvba vf vzcbegnag)).  As for the 6 x 6 arrangement, I'm not sure -- a wild guess might be rot13(fvapr n phor unf 6 snprf, n ulcrephor unf 6 "snprf" bs phorf, rnpu bs juvpu unf fvk fvqrf, juvpu jbhyq znxr 36 fdhnerf ba gur bhgfvqr bs gur ulcrephor)

Comment: Sry but this is not the intended answer. The answer I'm looking for is based on something simpler.